# Is there a formalization of normalization of impredicative system F?

Tags: lo.logic, type-systems, coq, normalization, agda

In particular Agda [seems not strong enough](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32859/logical-reations-for-an-impredicative-system-in-a-predicative-metatheory) to prove that.

Is the predicative Calculus of Inductive Constructions universes (Coq without Prop) sufficient?

How about with the impredicative Prop?

Comment: There's one here: https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/autosubst/doc/Ssr.SystemF_SN.html (see 
https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/autosubst/ for context — it's an exercise done with a new library for formalization).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Coq without Prop is not strong enough, because it's basically Martin-Löf type theory with universes.
- Coq with Prop is strong enough, because you can encode sets of normalizing terms via predicates $S : \mathrm{Term} \to \mathrm{Prop}$, and impredicative universal quantification lets you express arbitrary intersections.

Comment: Is there an existing Coq formalization?

Comment: @ŁukaszLew I couldn't find anything compelling online, but there is a Lego formalization by Altenkirch (1993!) described here: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/publ/tlca93.pdf

Comment: Found two more: 

 [Strong normalization for System F by HOAS on top of FOAS](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/15451/HOASonTopOfFOAS.pdf?sequence=2) 
 and  [Girard Normalization Proof in LEGO, page 67](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Lincoln_Wallen/publication/220806453_Investigations_into_Proof-Search_in_a_System_of_First-Order_Dependent_Function_Types/links/54b694830cf2e68eb27ea1a6.pdf#page=70)

Comment: Here's one in Coq! https://github.com/coq-community/autosubst/blob/master/examples/ssr/SystemF_CBV.v