# For which type systems have normalizaton proofs been formalized?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, embeddings

I am trying to understand what the open problems are in the area of formalizing proofs of normalization for type systems.

Obviously STLC has been done many times.

For predicative System F, I found one instance: [Equations for Hereditary Substitution in Leivant’s Predicative System F: a case study](https://sozeau.gitlabpages.inria.fr/www/research/publications/Equations_for_Hereditary_Substitution_in_Leivants_Predicative_System_F:_a_case_study.pdf). That paper claims to not be the first, so which ones are earlier?

For impredicative System F, I found [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40942/is-there-a-formalization-of-normalization-of-impredicative-system-f).

For anything in between predicative System F and dependent type theory, I haven't found anything. Are there any results in this area?

For dependent type theory, I am aware of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.02462.pdf) which uses a QIT approach by Thorsten Altenkirch and Ambrus Kaposi. I am somewhat confused by the statement that the paper makes "some of the naturality and functoriality properties
are left as holes". Does this imply that **formalization of normalization of dependent type theory is still an open problem?**

Also, **is a formalization of normalization for dependent type theory without QITs an open problem?**

Comment: Are you aware of the [Coq in Coq](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Bruno.Barras/publi/coqincoq.pdf) paper? It formalizes the strong normalization proof for the calculus of constructions.

Comment: @paulotorrens So contrary to my assumptions, there is very little gap between paper proofs of normalization and formalized ones? Thanks.

Comment: You might also like this paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3158111